# Jenkins maven release plugin fails with no error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use Jenkins M2 Release Plugin. My Jenkins version is 1.531.

I have a project with one parent pom and 2 modules. When I do;

> maven release: prepare

I get an error like this with no explaination:

```
INFO: Reactor Summary:
Sep 23, 2013 1:01:18 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: 
Sep 23, 2013 1:01:18 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: myproject-parent .................................. FAILURE [0.209s]
Sep 23, 2013 1:01:18 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: myproject ......................................... SKIPPED
Sep 23, 2013 1:01:18 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: myproject-demo .................................... SKIPPED
```

And in my parent POM I have

```
  <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh:myREPOURL</developerConnection>
</scm>

<plugins>
  ..
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
```

I saw some posters reported this is bug with some previous jenkins versions but ONLY in slave, I run on jenkins master.

Maybe I set release and development versions incorrectly? not sure

Comment: Did you look in the whole output? Most times the actual error leading to build failure hides itself somewhere in the output. It's kind of easy to miss.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel no errors in output nothing different than I see when I do a succesful maven release clean, BTW do i need to add scm tags to my pom file with a git url?

Comment: Yes, you need to define the SCM connection in your pom. Maven uses it to comitt the pom with the new version numbers.

Comment: Did you mean to have a space after `release:` and before `prepare` ? Or was that a typo.

Comment: @Spring Um, I don't really know this one exactly by heart but it sounds about right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We got the same problem, solved it by rechecking SCM in pom.xml and Entering Username and Password in jenkins when starting the Release Plugin.